# Random sum a.s convergence and convergence in probability

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, random-variables

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables such that $$\mathbb{P}[X_i=1]=\mathbb{P}[X_i=-1]=\frac{1}{2}$$
Consider the sum $S_n=\Sigma_{k=1}^nX_k.$

How can we show that for any $\epsilon>0$
$$\frac{S_n}{n^{1/2+\epsilon}}$$
converges to $0$ almost surely?

Moreover, how can we prove that $\frac{S_n}{n^{1/2}}$ does not converge to $0$ in probability?

I have done some work but I dont think its correct. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Try computing the variance.  Overall, you could closely follow a proof you know of the Law of Large numbers.

Comment: @Michael this is not really helpful.
 But I have tried using Chebyshev's inequality to show that the series $\Sigma \mathbb{P}(|S_n/n^{1/2+\epsilon}|<\epsilon)$ goes to 0 etc... But no use

Comment: Why is it no use? And perhaps first show a sparsely sampled sequence goes to zero (which is a standard proof for LLN).  Like take $n=(1+\epsilon)^k$.

Comment: What if it is sparsely going to 0? Does it mean the series itself goes to 0?

Comment: If you do not know that proof, then is this a problem set exercise that asks you to use some particular method you know?  How did you prove LLN? Fourth moment?

Comment: @Michael It doesnt even have to converge to 0. It should be just convergent.

Comment: Anyway the fourth moment method does not seem to work here.  I suspect you are supposed to use the other method which first shows $S_n/n^{1/2+\epsilon}$ goes to 0 with prob 1 over a sparsely sampled set of points $n$.  There is also the standard non-negativity trick, etc.

Comment: @Michael could you help me with that? At least show how to begin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22616/discussion-between-michael-and-l-g).